# How to solve meeting room booking conflict problem in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

When implementing a typical meeting room booking system with RDBMS, there will be two operations:

```
-- Check for any existing bookings that overlap with the period of noon-1pm
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookings WHERE room_id = 123 AND
end_time > '2015-01-01 12:00' AND start_time < '2015-01-01 13:00';

-- If the previous query returned zero:
INSERT INTO bookings
(room_id, start_time, end_time, user_id)
VALUES (123, '2015-01-01 12:00', '2015-01-01 13:00', 666);
```

> code from: Designing Data Intensive Applications (page 249) -- Martin Kleppmann

And we'll need to set the isolation level to serializable to avoid the case where two users think there are no conflicts and insert two conflicting bookings.

My question is:

Assuming that we model each booking time slot as a document, how do we implement a system that can avoid conflicting bookings in MongoDB?

- I am more curious about how MongoDB handles concurrent transactions.
- Let's say I want to allow users to book any timeslot possible, not just the predefined time slot.
- Suppose user A wants to book timeslot **T1**, and B wants to book timeslot **T2**, and **T1** and **T2** overlap with each other. It's very possible two users get to the booking pages at the same time, and check with MongoDB and find no conflicts, and they both decide to insert the two timeslots that conflict with each other into DB.
- In RDBMS, we set the isolation level to solve this issue, what about MongoDB?

Comment: What do you mean by `And we'll need to set the isolation level to serializable`?

Comment: @MuratColyaran In RDBMS, we use isolation level to control how concurrent transactions affect each other. and in this case, serializable has to be used.

Comment: Hey @JohntheTraveler, were you able to find a solution ? I'm trying to solve something similar.

Answer (score 0):

It is atomic, when you execute an operation on document. There're transactions in Mongo like SQL has.

It might be helpful; https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Comment: but here I'm doing two operations:

1. check if there are conflicting bookings (documents) in mongoDB

2. if not, then insert the booking (a new document) into mongoDB

I suppose the two operations are not atomic?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what do you mean by `And we'll need to set the isolation level to serializable` but I'd add an additional layer that sends a request when the user selects between two dates before making a reservation.

So, on the API side. You must have a list endpoint that returns booked and selected dates.

F.e:

```
{
    "reservations": [
        {
            "userId": "1234567",
            "startDate": "19-08-2021",
            "endDate": "22-08-2021"
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

And on the front-end side, you can show the dates between `startDate` and `endDates` occupied.
And when the user selects between two dates, you can send a request that has the selected dates.

f.e endpoint is POST `/reservations/{roomId}/selected`

Then you can flag the room as selected for 300 seconds for example.

```
[
    {
        "roomId": "1234456",
        "selected": true,
        "booked": false
    }
    ...
]
```

When the user payed for the room or something. You can flag the room booked

```
[
    {
        "roomId": "1234456",
        "selected": false,
        "booked": true
    }
    ...
]
```

If the user didn't make payment in that 300 seconds, you can redirect him to the main screen. And flag the room `booked: false` again.

Edit:

I wasn't sure what's `isolation level` while writing the anser. But as I give you an example, I think you can use the same system. You can flag the room `selected: true` until payment transacted

Comment: Thank you, but I am more curious about how MongoDB handles concurrent transactions.

Let's say I want to allow users to book any timeslot possible, not just the predefined time slots as in your design.

Suppose user A wants to book timeslot T1, and B wants to book timeslot T2, and  T1 and T2 overlap with each other.

It's very possible two users get to the booking pages at the same time, and find no conflicts by querying MongoDB, and they both insert the two timeslots that conflict with each other into DB.

In RDBMS, we set the isolation level to solve this issue, what about MongoDB?

Comment: @JohntheTraveler If you implement an additional layer to your front-end, and flag your room selected or something you don't have to worry about conflicts. Because you'd be able to check the user has selected the room before you redirect them to the payment screen.. The method you are saying can also work but you have to create a new collection, model and so many other things. You'll also have to calculate the dates in the every month.. This is a lot of work.